# How to determine full command with args given a pid (or port in use)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ps, lsof

I've got this nice bash function for telling me the pid using a port:

```
using_port() {
  lsof -i:${1}
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    43988 gordon   9u   IPv4 0xecaac2af83bf0aa7      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Is there a way to easily get the full command that was run, including the path and args? Bonus points for updating the example function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command_using_port() {
    ps -p $(lsof -i:$1 -Fp | cut -c 2-) -o args --no-headers
}
```

Consult relevant man pages for description of options (that's what I did!)

Comment: For some reason, if I have the command rails server running, I only get "rails" as the arg. I'd like to see all the args passed.